# Entity Reference saved in database but null on `$entity->get('entity_reference_id')`

Tags: 8, entities

I'm having a very bizarre issue with an entity relationship in my models.  I have 4 entity classes within Drupal: `DogEntity`, `BaseAnimalEntity`, `BaseToyEntity`, `DogToyEntity`.  The following entity relationship is expressed: `DogEntity` -> `DogToyEntity`.

I can see that the `DogEntity` table has a concrete value in the `DogToyEntity` column of the database.  However, when I load the `DogEntity` entity, and then try to load the `DogToyEntity` from the `DogEntity`'s id it returns a `null` value.  I don't understand why this is happening.

Below are the class definitions for the classes:

BaseAnimal Class:

```
abstract class BaseAnimal extends ContentEntityBase implements BaseAnimalInterface {
    /**
     * Everything is implemented correctly, the entity is created correctly
     * So I'm leaving stuff out for brevity
     */

    public function getArbitraryField() {
        // all getXFunctions follow the form: $this->get('value')->value;
        return $this->get('arbitrary_field')->value;
    }

    public static function baseFieldDefinitions(EntityTypeInterface $entity_type) {
        $fields = parent::baseFieldDefinitions($entity_type);

        // Standard field, used as unique if primary index.
        $fields['id'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('integer')
            ->setLabel(t('ID'))
            ->setDescription(t('The ID of the entity.'))
            ->setReadOnly(TRUE);
        // Standard field, unique outside of the scope of the current project.
        $fields['uuid'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('uuid')
            ->setLabel(t('UUID'))
            ->setDescription(t('The UUID of the entity.'))
            ->setReadOnly(TRUE);

        // elided other fields for brevity.

        return $fields;
    }
}
```

Dog Class:

```
/**
 * @ContentEntityType(
 *   id = "dog"
 *   ... eliding
 */
public class Dog extends BaseAnimal implements DogInterface {
    /**
     * Everything is implemented correctly, the entity is created correctly
     * So I'm leaving stuff out for brevity
     */

    public function getOtherArbitraryField() {
        // all getXFunctions follow the form: $this->get('value')->value;
        return $this->get('other_arbitrary_field')->value;
    }

    public function setDogToy(int $value) {
        $this->set('dog_toy_id', $value);
        return $this;
    }

    public function getDogToy() {
        return $this->get('dog_toy_id')->value;
    }

    public static function baseFieldDefinitions(EntityTypeInterface $entity_type) {
        $fields = parent::baseFieldDefinitions($entity_type);
        $fields['dog_toy_id'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('entity_reference')
            ->setLabel(t('Dog Toy'))
            ->setDescription(t('Dog\'s favorite toy.'))
            ->setSetting('target_type', 'dog_toy')
            ->setSetting('handler', 'default')
            ->setDisplayOptions('view', array(
                'label' => 'above',
                'weight' => -3,
              ))
            ->setDisplayConfigurable('view', TRUE);
        return $fields;
    }
}
```

Base Toy Class:

```
abstract class BaseToy extends ContentEntityBase implements BaseToyInterface {
    /**
     * Everything is implemented correctly, the entity is created correctly
     * So I'm leaving stuff out for brevity
     */

    public function getArbitraryField() {
        // all getXFunctions follow the form: $this->get('value')->value;
        return $this->get('arbitrary_field')->value;
    }

    public static function baseFieldDefinitions(EntityTypeInterface $entity_type) {
        $fields = parent::baseFieldDefinitions($entity_type);

        // Standard field, used as unique if primary index.
        $fields['id'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('integer')
            ->setLabel(t('ID'))
            ->setDescription(t('The ID of the entity.'))
            ->setReadOnly(TRUE);
        // Standard field, unique outside of the scope of the current project.
        $fields['uuid'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('uuid')
            ->setLabel(t('UUID'))
            ->setDescription(t('The UUID of the entity.'))
            ->setReadOnly(TRUE);

        // elided other fields for brevity.

        return $fields;
    }
}
```

Dog Toy Class:

```
/**
 * @ContentEntityType(
 *   id = "dog_toy"
 *   ... eliding
 */
public class DogToy extends BaseToy implements DogToyInterface {
    /**
     * Everything is implemented correctly, the entity is created correctly
     * So I'm leaving stuff out for brevity
     */

    public function getOtherArbitraryField() {
        // all getXFunctions follow the form: $this->get('value')->value;
        return $this->get('other_arbitrary_field')->value;
    }

    public static function baseFieldDefinitions(EntityTypeInterface $entity_type) {
        $fields = parent::baseFieldDefinitions($entity_type);
        // Unnecessary fields elided for brevity.
        return $fields;
    }
}
```

So these entities are created and work correctly.  The problem comes when I do something like:

```
$dog = Dog::create($fields);
$dog->save(); // now has ID of 1.

// do some other things...

$toy = DogToy::create($other_fields);
$toy->save(); // now has ID of 1.

// do some other things...

$dog->setDogToy($toy->id());
$dog->save();  // Now Dog->dog_toy_id = 1.
```

The above works perfectly.  The database will be populated with the appropriate relationship, and I'm happy.

Then I'll try to do something like:

```
$dog = Dog::load(1); // loads correctly
var_dump($dog); // In here, the value of dog_toy_id is set correctly to 1, see above.
$toy = DogToy::load($dog->getDogToy());
var_dump($toy); // and $toy will be NULL
```

I've tried several sorts of seemingly trivial troubleshooting, debugging, etc.  But I don't understand what is happening.  I can see that `dog_toy_id` is set within the `Dog` class and that the column has a `1` on the `Dog` table.  Something is happening in that `Toy::load()` and I don't understand what it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The entity reference field has no `value` property. Use `target_id` in `Dog::getDogToy()` instead:

```
public function getDogToy() {
    return $this->get('dog_toy_id')->target_id;
}
```

Or `entity` to get the entity directly:

```
public function getDogToy() {
    return $this->get('dog_toy_id')->entity;
}
```

Then you don't need to load the DogToy entity:

```
$toy = $dog->getDogToy();
```

Comment: Thank you for this.  I looked trough the documentation and I didn't see this.  Clearly I missed something.  [Entity Reference API](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Entity!Plugin!DataType!EntityReference.php/class/EntityReference/8.2.x) is where I looked.

Comment: Yes, for a base field you don't see this in the database. For a bundle field you would have found this out by looking at the column header. To check the main property of a field, see https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Field%21Plugin%21Field%21FieldType%21EntityReferenceItem.php/function/EntityReferenceItem%3A%3AmainPropertyName/8.2.x